# Persist emptyDir contents after pod restarts/redeploy?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have the following deployment on Kubernetes/GKE:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend
  labels:
    app: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: cluster-manager
      volumes:
        - name: nginx-config
          configMap:
            name: backend-nginx-config
        - name: static
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: media
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - name: backend
          image: ...
          imagePullPolicy: "Always"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: static
              mountPath: /backend/static
            - name: media
              mountPath: /backend/media
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: backend-config

        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          imagePullPolicy: "Always"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: static
              mountPath: /static
            - name: media
              mountPath: /media
            - name: nginx-config
              mountPath: /etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template
              subPath: nginx.conf
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: backend-config
```

Inside the same pod there are two containers, a Django Backend image as WSGI app and an nginx image that is basically running as a reverse proxy, serving static/media files from the backend container. While this works, reading from https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir and testing it, I've noticed that of course the `emtpyDir` volume is deleted after pod restarts or redeploy. Since for now I'm not using an external CDN to serve media files, is there a way to share data between the two containers persisting it?

I've tried using a Persistent Volume Claim but it doesn't work as the emptyDir volume since it mounts the first time an empty dir on the container and only AFTER it gets populated.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: backend-media-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: standard-rwo
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend
  labels:
    app: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: cluster-manager
      volumes:
        - name: nginx-config
          configMap:
            name: backend-nginx-config
        - name: static
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: media
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            - claimName: backend-media-pvc
      containers:
        - name: backend
          image: ...
          imagePullPolicy: "Always"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: static
              mountPath: /backend/static
            - name: media
              mountPath: /backend/media
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: backend-config

        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          imagePullPolicy: "Always"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: static
              mountPath: /static
            - name: media
              mountPath: /media
            - name: nginx-config
              mountPath: /etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template
              subPath: nginx.conf
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: backend-config
```

Comment: Plain Docker has some special behavior around named volumes that gets misinterpreted as a way to share files from one container to another.  This doesn't work reliably: it hides updates to the content in the image, it doesn't work in plain Docker using a bind mount, and it doesn't work in Kubernetes.  I'd avoid trying to "share files", and maybe approach this by building a second image that bundles the static assets into the revers proxy.

Comment: I see, would you be so kind to explain a bit more in details the approach you mentioned? I've never tried this approach. If you could provide also a very basic example would be awesome.